How do I find the reason my ceiling is leaking brownish stain?
My living room corner area is showing a dark stain in the ceiling that drips in the wall. We checked the bathroom upstairs to see if there is a leak, opened a hole in the wall, but we don't see any wet spots.
It stops, then couple weeks it came back again.
Where we can check? Is this is not related to the bathroom and where can I look for the issue?

Unless you only use that bathroom once every couple of weeks, I would check if it happens when it rains(roof/wall leaking).  Drywall does not like water, so might as well cut a hole in ceiling now where it is staining.  Can be a small hole just big enough to put an inspection camera in.

Bathroom leaks may be "plumbing adjacent", i.e. not directly related to the plumbing. Water on the floor, whether from someone who doesn't understand how to operate a shower curtain, overwatering houseplants or mopping the floor, can find it's way through corners that aren't caulked and under fixtures, think toilet. That can appear as leaks that may not correlate with using the fixtures in a traditional way.

As noted in other answers, water leaks can travel a considerable distance before becoming visible. This could be a leak from a wall or roof which just happens to be dripping off the wood at this point.

@jsotola Answers to past questions about water leaks, which see.

Some years back I had a small wet spot on the kitchen ceiling, which was under an upstairs bathroom.  That time, the wet spot was caused by the toilet bowl seal.  Replaced the wax seal on the toilet and the leak disappeared.
